# Why am I getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I do not return a pointer of my function?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have the following code:

```
void add_tree_nodes(tree_node* root, int nodes[], int size);

int main()
{

  int tree_nodes[] = {3, 1, 0, 2, 8, 6, 5, 9};
  tree_node* root = NULL;
  add_tree_nodes(root, tree_nodes, 8);

  printf("%d\n", root->data);
  printf("%d\n", root->left->data);
  printf("%d\n", root->right->data);

  return 0;
}

void add_tree_nodes(tree_node* root, int nodes[], int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    root = add_tree_node(root, nodes[i]);
  }
}
```

And when I run it I am getting **Segmentation fault (core dumped).** However, if I changed my function `add_tree_nodes()` to return `tree_node*` it works properly:

```
tree_node* add_tree_nodes(tree_node* root, int nodes[], int size);

int main()
{

  int tree_nodes[] = {3, 1, 0, 2, 8, 6, 5, 9};
  tree_node* root = NULL;
  root = add_tree_nodes(root, tree_nodes, 8);

  printf("%d\n", root->data);
  printf("%d\n", root->left->data);
  printf("%d\n", root->right->data);

  return 0;
}

tree_node* add_tree_nodes(tree_node* root, int nodes[], int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    root = add_tree_node(root, nodes[i]);
  }
  return root;
}
```

My question is why am I getting a Segmentation fault in the first piece of code? I thought that when I passed a pointer into a function the address of that block of code was passed, so whatever I do inside a function affects that thing the pointer is pointing.

Comment: Because C passes pointers by value.  After calling `add_tree_nodes(root, tree_nodes, 8)`, the `root` pointer in `main()` isn't changed.

Comment: @SteveSummit why isn't changed? So, it means it is always NULL even after the loop terminates?

Comment: Yes.  See the answers. After `tree_node* root = NULL;
  root = add_tree_nodes(root, tree_nodes, 8);`, root is still NULL.

Comment: Suppose you had `int x = 144; sqrt(x); printf("%d\n", x)`.  Would you ever expect this to not print 144?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a copy of the `root` pointer to `add_tree_nodes`. Presumably you allocate memory in `add_tree_nodes`. But this doesn't change the value of `root`. You need to use a double pointer (**root), and pass `&root`.

Comment: Yes, I am allocating memory in `add_tree_nodes()`.

Comment: Right, so the pointer returned by malloc is placed into a local variable (the `node` parameter), but is never set in the `node` variable in your main. So you still have a null pointer when you print the data.

Answer (score 0):

In your first piece of code your prototype for function `add_tree_nodes()` is,

```
void add_tree_nodes(tree_node* root, int nodes[], int size);
```

Notice the return type you gave was `void`. So, this line of code is wrong,

```
 root = add_tree_node(root, nodes[i]);
```

Because you are saying that add_tree_node returns a value.Your second Code corrects it.